# specifying a list as a command line argument in python

Tags: python

I am using getopt to process a command line optional argument, which should accept a list. Something like this:

```
foo.py --my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4,5]
```

But this trims everything after "[1,"

My questions are:
A) Is there a way to specify a list without converting it into a string? (using getopt)

B) If I am to convert the list into a string, how to convert this list to a string? e.g. something like  mylist.split("?") to get rid of square brackets ?? is there a better way?

Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two options that I can think of:

- Use [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), and use [`append`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#other-actions) action to specify what you want to do as: `foo.py --my_list=1 --my_list=2 ...`.
- Specify your commandline as `foo.py --my_list='1,2,3,4,5'`, and then use `x.split(',')` to get your values in a list.   You can use `getopt` or `optparse` for this method.

The advantage of the first method is that you can get integer values in the list directly, at the expense of the commandline being longer (but you can add a single-charecter option for `--my_list` if you want).  The advantage of the second is shorter command line, but after the `split()`, you need to convert the string values `'1'`, `'2'`, etc., to integers (pretty easy as well).

Comment: as this post is 5 years old, `optparse` is now deprecated for `argparse`

Comment: What do you mean by 'use append action'? It sounds exciting but not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck See https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html#standard-option-actions - they have an example of the "append" action: `parser.add_option("-t", "--tracks", action="append", type="int")`.

Comment: Please take a loot at my answer, as this one is older and not the preferable way to do this.

Answer (score 14):

If I can't use a standard parser (optparse or argparse) to my application then I use the ast.literal_eval function to parse input arguments of type list as follows:

```
import sys, ast

inputList = ast.literal_eval( sys.argv[1] )
print type( inputList )
print inputList
```

Let suppose that this code is stored in testParser.py file. By executing the script:

```
$ python testParser.py  "[1,2,3,4, [123, 456, 789], 'asdasd']"
```

we get the following output:

```
<type 'list'>
[1, 2, 3, 4, [123, 456, 789], 'asdasd']
```

So, using the secure enough ast.literal_eval function and inserting the list as a string of code we have the desirable result.

Useful links:

[Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should just enclose the argument in quotes?

```
foo.py "--my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4,5]"
```

Otherwise every space will be treated as a separator for arguments.

Comment: And that's not because of python but due to the shell which parses the arguments and provides them to the python program.

Comment: Partly true. On Windows the command line is just a string. And even UNIX does not have any special data structure that passes arguments to the program, it's still only a string. However, it's a widely implemented convention, but not universal. And yes, the C runtime has specifications for that.

Comment: You can also do `--my-list="[1, 2, 3, 4,5]"`.  I usually use this form because it's usually something like `--my-list="$MY_LIST"`.

Comment: Ah, I thought so much already but wasn't familiar enough with getopt to know whether that would work.

Answer (score 6):

An updated way is to use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library and add the list as a command line argument. This way, you don't have to do any manual parsing.

Example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        "-values",
        nargs="*",  # expects ≥ 0 arguments
        type=int,
        default=[35, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],  # default list if no arg value
    )
```

Which you would then call like this:

```
python3 someprogram.py -values 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is still a valid approach as of April 2020.

Answer (score 1):

From the python optparse help page:
"

```
parser.add_option("-f")
parser.add_option("-p", type="float", nargs=3, dest="point")
```

As it parses the command line

```
-f foo.txt -p 1 -3.5 4 -fbar.txt
```

optparse will set

```
options.f = "foo.txt"
options.point = (1.0, -3.5, 4.0)
options.f = "bar.txt"
```

"

Answer (score 0):

I have been redirected from the dup question:
[How to pass an array to python through command line - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926077/how-to-pass-an-array-to-python-through-command-line/36926259#36926259)

I’m answering that question:
The arguments on the command line are strings, they're not parsed like literals in the program.
argv construct the strings automatically to a list from command line arguments (as separated by spaces), in short, 
`sys.argv` is a list.

```
    from sys import argv
    cmd = "arr = {sys.argv[1]}".format(argv)
    exec(cmd)
    print(arr[2])
```