# python argh/argparse: How can I pass a list as a command-line argument?

Tags: python, python-argh

I'm trying to pass a list of arguments to a python script using the argh library.  Something that can take inputs like these:

```
./my_script.py my-func --argA blah --argB 1 2 3 4
./my_script.py my-func --argA blah --argB 1
./my_script.py my-func --argA blah --argB
```

My internal code looks like this:

```
import argh

@argh.arg('--argA', default="bleh", help='My first arg')
@argh.arg('--argB', default=[], help='A list-type arg--except it\'s not!')
def my_func(args):
    "A function that does something"

    print args.argA
    print args.argB

    for b in args.argB:
        print int(b)*int(b)  #Print the square of each number in the list
    print sum([int(b) for b in args.argB])  #Print the sum of the list

p = argh.ArghParser()
p.add_commands([my_func])
p.dispatch()
```

And here's how it behaves:

```
$ python temp.py my-func --argA blooh --argB 1
blooh
['1']
1
1

$ python temp.py my-func --argA blooh --argB 10
blooh
['1', '0']
1
0
1

$ python temp.py my-func --argA blooh --argB 1 2 3
usage: temp.py [-h] {my-func} ...
temp.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 2 3
```

The problem seems pretty straightforward: argh is only accepting the first argument, and treating it as a string.  How do I make it "expect" a list of integers instead?

I see [how this is done in optparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086556/specifying-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument-in-python), but what about the (not-deprecated) argparse?  Or using argh's much nicer decorated syntax?  These seem much more pythonic.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

With `argparse`, you just use `type=int`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg', nargs='+', type=int)
print parser.parse_args()
```

Example output:

```
$ python test.py -a 1 2 3
Namespace(arg=[1, 2, 3])
```

Edit: I'm not familiar with `argh`, but it seems to be just a wrapper around `argparse` and this worked for me:

```
import argh

@argh.arg('-a', '--arg', nargs='+', type=int)
def main(args):
    print args

parser = argh.ArghParser()
parser.add_commands([main])
parser.dispatch()
```

Example output:

```
$ python test.py main -a 1 2 3
Namespace(arg=[1, 2, 3], function=<function main at 0x.......>)
```

Comment: Awesome! I tweaked the code to include the line: @argh.arg('--argB', default=[], help='A list-type arg--except it\'s not!', nargs='+', type=int)  and argh liked it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, this is the correct way. The recent versions of Argh also support the "natural", more pythonic notation: `func(argA, *argB)` (though `*args` maps to `nargs='*'` instead of `nargs='+'`).

Comment: @jcollado : I see that when i use nargs= , i cannot do -a=1 2 3 . What I mean is that use '=' after the argument metavar. Any solution to let me use = for every arg. For ex in your example i wanna do ,          python test.py main -a=1 2 3

Comment: @Andy Mikhaylenko  The above question.

Comment: @AndyMikhaylenko I don't know of any straightforward way to do that. One alternative would be something like: `parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg', type=lambda s: [int(n) for n in s.split()])` and call the script using quotes: `python test.py --arg="1 2 3"`

Comment: @script_kiddie @jcollado the problem is in the `=` character. `-a 1 2` means "a = [1, 2]" while `-a=1 2` means "a = 1; some-positional-argument = 2".

Answer (score 1):

I order to have access to each parameter value, the following code may be helpful.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg', nargs='+', type=int)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print "first parameter:" + str(args["arg"][0])
print "second parameter:" + str(args["arg"][1])
print "third parameter:" + str(args["arg"][2])
```