# Python take user arguments as list

Tags: python

I have written a python script to get inputs from user but user input is getting splitted with ",". I dont want user input to get modified.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","--file_name", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ingress",type=list)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.file_name
print args.ingress
print(type(args.ingress))
```

Output:

```
./input_parse.py -f output.txt -i [["1,2,3,4"],80,90,"tcp"]
output.txt
['[', '[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ']', ',', '8', '0', ',', '9', '0', ',', 't', 'c', 'p', ']']
<type 'list'>
```

Expected Output:

```
output.txt
[["1,2,3,4"],80,90,"tcp"]
<type 'list'>
```

Later I need to iterate over the list and take list[0], list[1] and so on.

Comment: Change the type back to `str`. `type=list` makes Python call `list()` on the loaded string, and `list('foo')` returns a list of all characters.

Comment: No It's not working!

Comment: type=list does the same thing as list('foo') @poke

Comment: That’s what I said. Read my comment again.

Comment: ```>>> name = "Suresh"
>>> print(list(name))
['S', 'u', 'r', 'e', 's', 'h']```

Comment: @poke Please look at the expected output and then downvote my question!

Comment: change this line `parser.add_argument("-i", "--ingress",type=list)`, here you defined `type=list` make it `type=str`.

Comment: @Bijoy I need to iterate over the list

Comment: You can convert it to list by using `eval(string)`, but only if the value is from trusted source

Comment: Possible duplicates: [argparse option for passing a list as option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753701/argparse-option-for-passing-a-list-as-option), [python argh/argparse: How can I pass a list as a command-line argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398065/python-argh-argparse-how-can-i-pass-a-list-as-a-command-line-argument)

Answer (score 1):

The argument parser, takes everything as a string then applies the `type` you specified on the input. If you really need to pass a list, just convert back to a `str` and convert it to a list with a helper function:

#### Option 1:

you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","--file_name", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ingress",type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.file_name
print args.ingress
print(type(args.ingress))

def helper(x):
        l = x.split('|')
        ll = [[l[0]]]+l[1].split(',')
        ll[1], ll[2] = int(ll[1]), int(ll[2])
        return ll

args.ingress = helper(args.ingress)
print args.ingress 
print type(args.ingress)
```

And then pass the argument like this:

```
python /tmp/test.py -f output.txt -i "1,2,3,4|80,90,tcp"
```

The output will look as you expect it:

```
output.txt
1,2,3,4|80,90,tcp
<type 'str'>
[['1,2,3,4'], 80, 90, 'tcp']
<type 'list'>
```

#### Option 2:

This can also be changed to take a list:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","--file_name", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ingress",type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.file_name
print args.ingress
print(type(args.ingress))

def helper(x):
        l = x.split(']')
        l[0] = l[0].replace('[[','')
        l = l[:2]
        ll = [[l[0]]]+l[1].split(',')[1:]
        ll[1], ll[2] = int(ll[1]), int(ll[2])
        return ll

args.ingress = helper(args.ingress)
print args.ingress 
print type(args.ingress)
```

You call it like this:

```
python /tmp/test.py -f output.txt -i [["1,2,3,4"],80,90,"tcp"]
```

output:

```
output.txt
[[1,2,3,4],80,90,tcp]
<type 'str'>
[['1,2,3,4'], 80, 90, 'tcp']
<type 'list'>
```

#### Option 3:

Use `ast.literal_eval` (which is dangerous than `eval`, as anyone can inject code into your program and potentially harm your system):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ast
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f","--file_name", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i", "--ingress",type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.file_name
print args.ingress
print(type(args.ingress))

args.ingress = ast.literal_eval(args.ingress)
print args.ingress
print type(args.ingress)
```

call:

```
python /tmp/test.py -f output.txt -i '[["1,2,3,4"],80,90,"tcp"]'
```

output:

```
output.txt
[["1,2,3,4"],80,90,"tcp"]
<type 'str'>
[['1,2,3,4'], 80, 90, 'tcp']
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: If you replace `eval` with `ast.literal_eval` it becomes non-dangerous and (in my opinion) the best solution.

Comment: Why mention `eval` at all? Or, at least the grammar should be updated because as written it sounds like `literal_eval` is as dangerous as `eval`.