# Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a situation with some code where `eval()` came up as a possible solution.  Now I have never had to use `eval()` before but, I have come across plenty of information about the potential danger it can cause.  That said, I'm very wary about using it.

My situation is that I have input being given by a user:

```
datamap = input('Provide some data here: ')
```

Where `datamap` needs to be a dictionary.  I searched around and found that `eval()` could work this out. I thought that I might be able to check the type of the input before trying to use the data and that would be a viable security precaution.

```
datamap = eval(input('Provide some data here: ')
if not isinstance(datamap, dict):
    return
```

I read through the docs and I am still unclear if this would be safe or not.  Does eval evaluate the data as soon as its entered or after the `datamap` variable is called?

Is the `ast` module's `.literal_eval()` the only safe option?

Answer (score 318, accepted):

`datamap = eval(input('Provide some data here: '))` means that you actually evaluate the code *before* you deem it to be unsafe or not. It evaluates the code as soon as the function is called. See also [the dangers of `eval`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype, so the code won't be executed if it's not.

Use `ast.literal_eval` whenever you need [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). You shouldn't usually evaluate literal Python statements.

Comment: This isn't 100% correct advice since any bitwise operators (or overloaded operators) will fail. Eg. `ast.literal_eval("1 & 1")` will throw an error but `eval("1 & 1")` will not.

Comment: Just curious. Shouldn't we use expression parsers or something if we're expecting something like "1 & 1" ?

Comment: @thelinuxer you still should, yes; you just wouldn't be able to use `ast.literal_eval` for something like that (e.g. you could implement a parser manually).

Comment: @DanielvanFlymen - to me, your example shows that this *is* good advice.  When you don't want operators (like `&`) to be evaluated, you use `literal_eval`.  The fact that you can't put arbitrary code there to be executed is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 159):

[`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) only considers a small subset of Python's syntax to be valid:

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.

Passing `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /a-path-you-really-care-about')` into `ast.literal_eval()` will raise an error, but [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) will happily delete your files.

Since it looks like you're only letting the user input a plain dictionary, use `ast.literal_eval()`. It safely does what you want and nothing more.

Answer (score 87):

**eval:**
This is very powerful, but is also very dangerous if you accept strings to evaluate from untrusted input. Suppose the string being evaluated is "os.system('rm -rf /')" ? It will really start deleting all the files on your computer.
**ast.literal_eval:**
Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None, bytes and sets.
**Syntax:**

```
eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
import ast
ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
```

**Example:**

```
# python 2.x - doesn't accept operators in string format
import ast
ast.literal_eval('[1, 2, 3]')  # output: [1, 2, 3]
ast.literal_eval('1+1') # output: ValueError: malformed string


# python 3.0 -3.6
import ast
ast.literal_eval("1+1") # output : 2
ast.literal_eval("{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 3:'xyz'}") # output : {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 3:'xyz'}
# type dictionary
ast.literal_eval("",{}) # output : Syntax Error required only one parameter
ast.literal_eval("__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')") # output : error

eval("__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')") 
# output : start deleting all the files on your computer.
# restricting using global and local variables
eval("__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')",{'__builtins__':{}},{})
# output : Error due to blocked imports by passing  '__builtins__':{} in global

# But still eval is not safe. we can access and break the code as given below
s = """
(lambda fc=(
lambda n: [
    c for c in 
        ().__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__() 
        if c.__name__ == n
    ][0]
):
fc("function")(
    fc("code")(
        0,0,0,0,"KABOOM",(),(),(),"","",0,""
    ),{}
)()
)()
"""
eval(s, {'__builtins__':{}})
```

In the above code `().__class__.__bases__[0]` nothing but object itself. 
Now we instantiated all the **subclasses**, here our main `enter code here`objective is to find one class named **n** from it.

We need to `code` object and `function` object from instantiated subclasses. This is an alternative way from `CPython` to access subclasses of object and attach the system.

From python 3.7 ast.literal_eval() is now stricter. Addition and subtraction of arbitrary numbers are no longer allowed. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html?highlight=ast%20literal_eval)

Comment: i am using python 2.7 and i just checked its working fine on python 3.x. My bad i kept trying it on python 2.7

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("1+1")` does not work in python 3.7 and as said before, literal_eval should be limited to literals of those few data structures. It should not be able to parse a binary operation.

Comment: Could you explain your `KABOOM` code, please? Found it here: [`KABOOM`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: @winklerrr `KABOOM` is nicely explained here: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: `ast.literal_eval("1+1")` raises `ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1` on python 3.10.

Answer (score 56):

Python's *eager* in its evaluation, so `eval(input(...))` (Python 3) will evaluate the user's input as soon as it hits the `eval`, regardless of what you do with the data afterwards. Therefore, **this is not safe**, especially when you `eval` user input.

Use `ast.literal_eval`.

---

As an example, entering this at the prompt could be very bad for you:

```
__import__('os').system('rm -rf /a-path-you-really-care-about')
```

Answer (score 14):

In recent Python3 ast.literal_eval() "no longer parses simple strings"*, instead you are supposed to use the ast.parse() method to create an AST then interpret it.

---

** UPDATE (Q1:2023):  I sometimes get comments about the meaning of "simple strings" in this context. On reading up on the current status I've added this update to try and addresses that.*

I wrote this answer some time ago and I used the "simple string" phrase from my reference at the time, sadly I don't recall the source but it was probably getting outdated, but it is true that at one time this method expected something other than a string. So at the time this was a reference to Python 2 and that fact changed slightly in Python 3, but it does come with limitations. Then at some point I updated the code presented from Py2 to Py3 syntax, causing the confusion.

I hope this answer is still a complete example of how to write a safe parser that can evaluate arbitrary expressions under the control of the author that can then be used to interpret uncontrolled data by sanitising each parameter. Comments appreciated as I still use something similar in live projects!

So really the only update is that for very simple Python expressions `ast.iteral_eval(str: statements)` is now, if I understand correctly, regarded as safe.

And this answer is *I hope* still a working *minimal* example of how to implement something similar to `ast.literal_eval(str: statements)` for a greater diversity of functions, methods and datatypes but still in a simple way that can be considered safe.  I am sure there are others methods but that would be out of context as unrelated to the topic of this question.

---

Here is a complete example of using ast.parse() correctly in Python 3.6+ to evaluate simple arithmetic expressions safely.

```py
import ast, operator, math
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)

def safe_eval(s):

    def checkmath(x, *args):
        if x not in [x for x in dir(math) if not "__" in x]:
            raise SyntaxError(f"Unknown func {x}()")
        fun = getattr(math, x)
        return fun(*args)

    binOps = {
        ast.Add: operator.add,
        ast.Sub: operator.sub,
        ast.Mult: operator.mul,
        ast.Div: operator.truediv,
        ast.Mod: operator.mod,
        ast.Pow: operator.pow,
        ast.Call: checkmath,
        ast.BinOp: ast.BinOp,
    }

    unOps = {
        ast.USub: operator.neg,
        ast.UAdd: operator.pos,
        ast.UnaryOp: ast.UnaryOp,
    }

    ops = tuple(binOps) + tuple(unOps)

    tree = ast.parse(s, mode='eval')

    def _eval(node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Expression):
            logger.debug("Expr")
            return _eval(node.body)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Str):
            logger.debug("Str")
            return node.s
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Num):
            logger.debug("Num")
            return node.value
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Constant):
            logger.info("Const")
            return node.value
        elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):
            logger.debug("BinOp")
            if isinstance(node.left, ops):
                left = _eval(node.left)
            else:
                left = node.left.value
            if isinstance(node.right, ops):
                right = _eval(node.right)
            else:
                right = node.right.value
            return binOps[type(node.op)](left, right)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp):
            logger.debug("UpOp")
            if isinstance(node.operand, ops):
                operand = _eval(node.operand)
            else:
                operand = node.operand.value
            return unOps[type(node.op)](operand)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            args = [_eval(x) for x in node.args]
            r = checkmath(node.func.id, *args)
            return r
        else:
            raise SyntaxError(f"Bad syntax, {type(node)}")

    return _eval(tree)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    assert safe_eval("1+1") == 2
    assert safe_eval("1+-5") == -4
    assert safe_eval("-1") == -1
    assert safe_eval("-+1") == -1
    assert safe_eval("(100*10)+6") == 1006
    assert safe_eval("100*(10+6)") == 1600
    assert safe_eval("2**4") == 2**4
    assert safe_eval("sqrt(16)+1") == math.sqrt(16) + 1
    assert safe_eval("1.2345 * 10") == 1.2345 * 10

    print("Tests pass")
```

Comment: What if I wanna parse a ast.Lambda, say safe_eval("lambda x: x * 2")? Many thanks

Comment: The post is specifically about simple arithmetic evaluation without parsing code, not about parsing Python syntax.  If I can do "lambda x: x * 2".  Then I could possibly do "lambda x: format_hdd()". Anyway to answer your question, where X is a variable, use safe_eval("X * 2".replace("X", "55"))    In my actual application I use f-string like syntax, e.g. safe_eval(f"{X} * 2")

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer parses simple strings"? AFAIK, its behaviour hasn't changed across Python versions, like if you look at [the docs for 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), the description is pretty much the same. It never allowed parsing arbitrary expressions, if that's what you mean, and it never stopped parsing strings, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @wjandrea  I started in Python 1.x  (can't recall what the x was)  When revisting old code I found the issue. IIRC, the words are exactly as written in the PEP that removed "simple strings" due to that being a vector for miscreants.  I agree I should have linked that refernce when I wrote the answer. But that was some time back. Not sure I could find it again, but I will try for completeness. In any case the answer is still a valid example of how to write a simple interpreter to evaluate expression data, that you have no control over, without compromising security.

Comment: @JayM But what does "simple strings" mean?

Comment: As I said, I recall that was the words in the explanation I came across of why my old code had to be re-written.  I did not link that reference as I assumed that the change was a well known one.  I'd not used AST for several years until I needed to parse user supplied Verilog files if you a curious.  Obviously I did not want a user putting anything in their macros that could be misused.  The old code would have from Py2 or perhaps even late Py1. I really don't remember.

Comment: @wjandrea  I've undated the answer in a way that should answer your question

Comment: @JayM: I think you are confused about the "simple string" thing. `ast.literal_eval` was added in 2.6, and did not exist in 1.x. [Since 2.6](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), `ast.literal_eval` has taken a `node_or_string`, which has remained unchanged all the way to 3.11.

Answer (score 9):

If all you need is a user provided dictionary, a possible better solution is [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).  The main limitation is that JSON dicts ("objects") require string keys.  Also you can only provide literal data, but that is also the case for `ast.literal_eval`.