# How to pass an array to python through command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass an array to the python

```
import sys
arr = sys.argv[1]
print(arr[2])
```

My command is

```bash
python3 test.py [1,2,3,4,5] 0
```

I hope the result it

```
2
```

However, it is

```
,
```

Comment: another similar answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605631/passing-a-list-to-python-from-command-line

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5]` is a filename globbing pattern. It matches any filename whose name is a single character that's either 1 through 5 or a comma.

Comment: If you want to use it as a literal argument to the script, you need to put it in quotes.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The elements of `argv` are strings, they're not parsed like literals in the program.

You should just pass a comma-separated string (without the brackets):

```
python3 test.py 1,2,3,4,5 0
```

and then use `split()` to convert it to an array.

```
import sys
arr = sys.argv[1].split(',')
print(arr[2])
```

Comment: Great answer. Just wanted to add that, in case you want to use the list as an array, you can convert it like:
arr = sys.argv[1].split(',') ;

arr = np.array([float(i) for i in arr])

Comment: What if I would like to pass a 2d array containing all kinds of string including commas?

I've tried defining it as a r"""[["","",""]["","","",]]""" but my first element still is just up to the first comma. Is there no way to pass the entire array as a single string?

Comment: @Johnson If you want to use Python syntax in the argument, you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it. You'll also need to put it in quotes to prevent the shell from parsing all the brackets and quotes.

Comment: @Barmar Thans for your suggestion, but it doesn't work for me. I tried ast.literal_eval(sys.argv) but it just turns the entire arguments array into a string, like this: '['path/main.py', '[[1, 000, Some, 'data'],[ 'my', 'array']]'] with the quotes appearing in random places. my argument is """[["Some data", "in my array"], ["That's not broken", "like what ast.literal_eval() returns"]]"""

Comment: @Johnson Please ask a new question, showing exactly what you're typing in the CLI, and what you tried in the code.

Comment: @Barmar Sure thing: [How do I pass an array of strings to a python script as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74727714/how-do-i-pass-an-array-of-strings-to-a-python-script-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 13):

Commandline arguments are strings. Even integers have to be converted from string to `int`. If you use the list syntax you show in your example, you'll need to run the argument through some sort of parser (your own parser, something from `ast`, or `eval`-- but don't use `eval`). But there's a simpler way: Just write the arguments separately, and use a slice of `sys.argv` as your list. Space-separated arguments is the standard way to pass multiple arguments to a commandline program (e.g., multiple filenames to `less`, `rm`, etc.).

```
python3 test.py -n a b c 1 2 3
```

First you'd identify and skip arguments that have a different purpose (`-n` in the above example), then simply keep the rest:

```
arr = sys.argv[2:]
print(arr[3])   # Prints "1"
```

PS. You also need to protect any argument from the shell, by quoting any characters with special meaning(`*`, `;`, spaces that are part of an argument, etc.). But that's a separate issue.

Comment: You'll get downvotes for suggesting `eval`...

Comment: Well, I didn't exactly... but you're right, thanks for the warning :-)

Comment: @nekomatic that's just `evil`