# Input two dimensional n*n array in python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, input

I am trying to take two dimensional array  input in python which can have n number of Rows and Columns. What I have tried is

```
x =  raw_input()[2:-2].split(',')
```

My input is following

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,1,2,3],[9,5,1,2]]
```

What output I am getting output

> ['1', '2', '3', '4]', '[5', '1', '2', '3]', '[9', '5', '1', '2']

I want to get array as same as my input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec('x=' + raw_input())
#in x is now what you wanted, [[1,2,3,4],[5,1,2,3],[9,5,1,2]]
```

or [more safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval):

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(raw_input())
```

Comment: Thank you.. Worked Perfectly

Comment: The exec is something you have  to avoid. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Answer (score 4):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is designed for this goal ( it's safe), see usage in code sample below:

```
import ast

s = '[[1,2,3,4],[5,1,2,3],[9,5,1,2]]'
ast.literal_eval(s)
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3], [9, 5, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check an older answer on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21163749/2194843

```
$ cat /tmp/test.py

import sys, ast
inputList = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
print(type(inputList))
print(inputList)

$ python3  /tmp/test.py '[[1,2,3,4],[5,1,2,3],[9,5,1,2]]'

<class 'list'>
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 1, 2, 3], [9, 5, 1, 2]]
```